# Where is mistake?

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me finding where I have made mistake?

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION `count_photos_in_gallery`(`tmp_gallery_id` INT(11) NOT NULL) RETURNS TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED
BEGIN
    DECLARE `tmp_count` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT COUNT(`id`) INTO `tmp_count` FROM `photos_items` WHERE `gallery_id`=`tmp_gallery_id` LIMIT 1;

    RETURN `tmp_count`;
END//
```

Error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'NOT NULL) RETURNS TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED BEGIN DECLARE `tmp_count`
>   TINYINT(3) UNSI' at line 1

Comment: Well, how can we find the mistake if we don't know what the problem is?

Comment: why do you think there's a mistake? What's the error you get?

Comment: define READS SQL DATA after your returns statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change function declaration, parameters cannot have NOT NULL option -

```
...
CREATE FUNCTION `count_photos_in_gallery`(`tmp_gallery_id` INT(11))
  RETURNS TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED
...
```

Comment: ok, i figured it out, but tell my why?

Comment: 'NULL' and 'NOT NULL' are column definition attributes (from CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statements). CREATE FUCTION syntax does not allow it.

Comment: @marverix why you need it not null?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `count_photos_in_gallery`(`tmp_gallery_id` INT(11)) RETURNS TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED
BEGIN
    DECLARE `tmp_count` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT COUNT(`id`) INTO `tmp_count` FROM `photos_items` WHERE `gallery_id`=`tmp_gallery_id` LIMIT 1;

    RETURN `tmp_count`;
END//
```